# Clarity regarding the use of sample() function in R to set up training and test sets for ML.

Tags: r, sampling

I am trying to understand this example of the KNN algorithm in R by Datacamp: [Machine Learning in R for beginners](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/machine-learning-in-r#sets)

I am having trouble understanding how they execute sampling to set up the training and test data sets.

I am able to follow the code till this line:

```
ind <- sample(2, nrow(iris), replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.67, 0.33))
```

It is my understanding that this creates a vector of length equal to `nrow(iris)`, with the vector values being either `1` or `2` and the probabilities of these values being chosen being `0.67` and `0.33`, respectively.

Thus, we get the following output:

```
> ind
  [1] 1 1 2 1 2 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 [58] 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 2 2 1 2 1 1 1
[115] 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 1 1
```

In the next step, they create the training set using the following code:

```
iris.training <- iris [ind==1, 1:4]
```

This line presumably produces a data frame consisting of all the rows for which `ind == 1`.

```
head(iris.training)
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
1           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2
2           4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2
4           4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2
7           4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3
9           4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2
10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1
```

My question is how are the variable `ind` and the `iris` data set related. That is, how does R know which lines to pick up (which lines have `ind == 1`) from the original `iris` data set, as there seems to be no connection between `ind` and the `iris` data set. The only time the `iris` data set is mentioned when setting up `ind` is to determine the sample size (number of samples to be chosen) using `nrow(iris)` in `ind <- sample(2, nrow(iris), replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.67, 0.33))`.

Comment: `ind==1` returns a logical vector.  Then `[` subsets iris, taking values where the vector is TRUE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is how are the variable ind and the iris data set related.

They're not, but they needn't be. For example, there is no intrinsic relationship between the numbers 1-5 and the iris dataset, yet

```r
iris[1:5, ]
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#> 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#> 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
#> 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
```

<sup>Created on 2018-08-05 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).</sup>

It would be a bit clearer to say `ind <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), nrow(iris), replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.67, 0.33))` and then `iris[ind, ]` to emphasize that `ind` is an index of rows to select rather than the result a comparison of variables within `iris`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, they are not related. We have created the vector "ind" for the purpose of splitting the given data set into train data set and test dataset without any bias such that the accuracy of the model could be more efficient.
As you know that, we have to split the data set into two parts. but we can't simply split the dataset as iris[1:456] and iris[456: ] as we are ignoring the last species of the iris dataset since the dataset is arranged in order of species attribute.
So we create this "ind" vector to randomly split the dataset such that it contains the data related to all the species in each split proportionally and in the same ratio.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).